# Create an object from a string... kind of

Tags: javascript

I'm not the best at javascript so I don't even know how to do this particular thing and if it can even be done.

So, say I have a string variable that contains someone's username. Then I want to create an object for that user along with the number of points that person has already gotten. So, for example, I'd have people with names 'John' and 'Mark'.

```
points.John = 1
points.Mark = 42
```

And so on. The thing is, I don't know how to do this, or if there's a better way.

Comment: You can declare `var points = {}` and the code above will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your string looks something like this:

```
var str = "John";
```

You can simply:

```
var points = {};
points[str] = 1;
```

---

```
console.log(points.John);
> 1
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/5Lu22f6d/).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an array?

```
var points = [];
points['John'] = 1;
points['Mark'] = 42;

var key = 'Mark';
alert(points[key]);
```

This should work, and be quite elegant?

Answer (score 0):

If points is an object, you can do it like this:

```
var name = 'Mark';
points[name] = 42;
```